# Capybara: Unable to find css for collection_select and text_field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, capybara

I have a `collection_select` and `text_field_tag` like this:

```
<%= form_tag method_path(@test.id), method: :get  do %>
  <%= collection_select(:test, :id, Test.all, :id, :id, prompt: true, include_blank: 'Select Test') %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:input_test_questions, 'Test ids') %>
  <%= submit_tag "Add" %>
<% end %>
```

This generates the following html:

```
<select name="test[id]" id="test_id"><option value="">Select Test</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="input_test_questions" id="input_test_questions" value="Test ids">
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add">
```

I am trying to write integration test using `Capybara` for the above. To select and input I wrote like this:

```
select "2", from: "#test_id"
fill_in "input_test_questions", with: "1"
```

But I am getting the following errors:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find css "#test_id"
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "input_test_questions" that is not disabled
```

How can I rectify the error so that `Capybara` finds and selects and fills with the above options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `from` option of [select](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions#select-instance_method) is used to locate the <select> element by its name, id, test_id attribute, or label text. It does not take a CSS selector.

```
select "2", from: "test_id" # find by id
select "2", from: "test[id]" # find by name
```

`fill_in "input_test_questions", with: "1"` should work as written against the HTML shown, unless you have JS/CSS behavior that is hiding the text input on the page. If you are hiding it then Capybara can't fill it in because a user wouldn't be able to.

Note: It shoudln't really be possible for the error message you show `Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find css "#test_id"` to come from the code you show, unless you're using a REALLY old version of Capybara. Hopefully that was just an incorrect copy/paste from other attempts you made.

Comment: When I run `gem list`, it shows this: `capybara (3.24.0, 3.22.0)`. I used the name for `select` like this `select "2", from: "test[id]"`. I got the following error: `Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find select box "test[id]" that is not disabled and Unable to find input box with datalist completion "test[id]" that is not disabled`. Same error when I use `test_id`.

Comment: User can select from the dropdown and input the values in the test_field. I do not know why capybara cannot find it.

Comment: @Laxman It sounds like you're not actually on the page you think you are.  If you're running headless swap to showing the browser ,or have it take a screenshot, and see what's actually on the page,  The other possibility is you have a JS widget adding behavior to the two fields which is hiding the original fields (select2, etc)

Comment: I found my mistake. In `erb` file the `collection_select` and `text_field` were inside a condition block which was not satisfied in the test file. So they were not displayed. I changed it and made changes as per your answer and it worked.

Comment: @Laxman Glad you figured out -- If my answer helped you don't forget to accept it (the checkmark) so your question gets marked as answered.